# Python, True/False, integrate function into program

Tags: python, boolean

I'm relatively new to python. I want to make a program that checks if a date is valid or not. I wrote the function code to check for leap years so far. But I want to integrate into the bigger program that checks for the validity of the month and date as well. How can I say in the last line "when C is true continue with a certain if else logic (...code that I will write later)" and "when C is false continue with this other if else logic"

```
def leap_year(c):

    if c % 4 == 0 and y % 100 != 0:
        print("True (Non-Centurial)")
    else:
        if c % 400 == 0:
            print("True (Centurial)")
        else:
            print("False")
    pass



    for c == True:

    ...(my if else statements)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be what you're looking for.

```
if(c): # Checks if C is True, 
    then… # If so, it gets in
return … # Otherwise, it goes other way
```

Keep in mind your **leap_year** function, must return something in oder to make this work

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a if-else structure using the `elif` keyword:

```
if c % 4 == 0 and y % 100 != 0:
    print("True (Non-Centurial)")
elif c % 400 == 0:
    print("True (Centurial)")
elif condition1:
    pass
elif contition2:
    pass
else
    print("False")
```